# Multiple alternate URL's (google meta)

Tags: meta, canonical-link

Just a quick question, I have a URL, which has alternate URL for mobile, and alternate URL for just another version of a page.

Is it okay to put in meta (in MAIN PAGE) something like:

```
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="VER1">
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="VER2">
```

...and on that pages I put canonical, to the MAIN PAGE?

Tnx